# Wordpress Show Parent Category Description for Sub-categories

Tags: categories, description

I'm using the Category description, for the parent category, to display above the posts on the category.php page.

[image: Parent Category page, showing desc above two posts]

But, this desc doesn't show on any sub-categories of this parent category, and there is no desc being added to each sub-category (there are over 270 cats in total, so duplicating desc from parents to subs would be tedious at best!)

**Is there way to show the Parent categories desc for the parent and all it's subcategories?**

Answer (score 1):

### Approach number one

If you are hard-coding a theme and you are writing your own *category.php* template, the first thing you have to do is to know what category you are displaying. You can use [get_queried_object()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/) to do that, which will return the current queried object.

```
$category = get_queried_object();
```

In your case you are calling the *category.php* template so it will return the queried category object.

The category object will be an instance of the [WP term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) class. And as you can see in the docs, it contains the parent attribute.

```
$parent_cat_id = $category->parent;
```

Then, you can get the parent category description as follows:

```
$description = category_description($parent_cat_id);
```

See the docs for [category_description()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/category_description/)

Of course you will also have to check if the current category has a parent or not. You can do that with a simple if statement:

```
if($category->parent > 0){
$parent_cat_id = $category->parent;
}
```

Please note that by default, the parent attribute is set to 0. That means that if your value of `$category->parent` is equal to 0, that category does not have a parent. It is a primary category.

### Approach number two

If you want to use filters, then you could use the [category_description](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/category_description/) hook, which filters the category description for display.

Insert the following [add_filter()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) call into your *functions.php* or custom plugin:

```
function wpse_display_parent_category_description($description, $category_id){

    $category = get_category($category_id);
    
    // Return the parent category description if it's a child category
    if($category->parent > 0){
    $parent_cat_id = $category->parent;
    return category_description($parent_cat_id);
    }

    // Or just return the original description if it's a primary category
    return $description;
}

add_filter('category_description', 'wpse_display_parent_category_description', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I prefer the filter method, but it throws an error:
    Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function display_parent_category_description(),

Comment: @revive Ups, sorry for that. Updated the answer. The thing is you must provide the accepted args parameter to the add_filter() function. In this case, the category_description hook accepts 2 arguments. Don't forget to mark it as accepted if it helped you. Have a nice day!

Comment: Ah, I didn't even catch that #facepalm.. I made that change but it doesn't show the parent cat desc on the child cat.. I var_dump'd the $category->parent var and it's null.. on a child category, with a parent cat that does have a desc.. thoughts??

Comment: @revive In old WP versions the `$category->parent` does not exist. It was named `$category->category_parent`. Which WP version are you using?

Comment: We're running 5.7.1

Comment: What does a var dump for $category say? That's weird.

Comment: var_dump on the $category shows '208' , which is the ID for this category (parent is 206)

Comment: @revive So it's not returning the category object, but the category ID. Please do a $cat = get_category($category) then, to get the category as an object. After that you can use $cat->parent. I will check this later and update my answer again. Do not have an active WP installation here to test things, sorry for that.

Comment: That should work.. and then I realize that my cat structure is:
Parent (no desc) - First Child (desc for all subs) - Second Child - Third Child.
So, it's not the top-level parent, but the first child desc I need !! 
Or, better yet, to get the desc of whatever parent cat has one..

Comment: @revive So yeah, the docs mention that $category is a WP Term instance but it's not. It's actually the category id.